# How exactly does ASKE (Alpha Secure Key Establishment) in Zigbee work?

Tags: authentication, key-exchange, reference-request, access-control

I am working on [Zigbee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) security. For key establishment, some approaches are given in Zigbee. Some of them are:

- ASKE (Alpha Secure Key Establishment),
- ASAC (Alpha Secure Access Control), and
- SKKE (Symmetric Key Key Establishment).

I tried to do my own research, but didn't get proper information on the web. I would like to know what these mechanisms are, and how do they establish a key between two devices?

At least, where can I get the information about these mechanisms?

Comment: can anybody help me?

Comment: You've asked a pretty broad question, and I haven't seen too many questions / answers about Zigbee here. Basically you're waiting for a Zigbee specialist to come across this page. This could be soon, late or never. I would not necessarily hold my breath, if you've got any other places to ask (outside the stackexchange network) I would certainly do so. And please report back if you do get an answer by other means. No answer here doesn't mean an unwillingness to answer, it may be that we just don't know.

Comment: The protocols are described in the Zigbee standard. I googled for ‘zigbee specification’ and the first hit was from the official alliance page. Section 4.4.2 describes the key establishment protocols.